# Importing Polish character file in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a csv with polish characters in it but when I am importing in SAS , certain polish characters are being replaced by "?" or any other random variable , How do I handle this.
I have a list of all the possible polish characters and I dont mind it being replaced by its english counterpart

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the appropriate file encoding on your `infile` statement, e.g. `encoding="UTF-8"`.

SAS Documentation > http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/61893/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002610945.htm

Comment: You may also need to use the appropriate session encoding.

Comment: I tried what Chris is saying but my SAS doesnt have the license to use it , However It will work if I import file in xls or xlsx format instead of csv as csv in itself converting those characters into wierd stuff. But again my SAS doesnt have the privilege to use dbms=excel. I'm able to import using manual option - File - import data -excel but that will not make my process automated. I'm looking for any other way around.

Comment: If it's a CSV file, just use a datastep and `infile ... dlm=','` to read it in, no need for any license.