# Importing SPSS file in SAS - Discrepancies in Language

Tags: unicode, import, sas

I am having trouble importing an SPSS file into SAS. The code I am using is:

```
proc import datafile = "C:\SAS\Germany.sav"
     out=test
     dbms = sav
     replace;
 run;
```

All the data are imported, but the problem is that some of the values of the variables have slightly different names. So, for instance in the SPSS file, the value of variable "A", is "KÖL", but when imported in SAS it becomes "KÃ–L".

What I am thinking is that the problem might be based on the fact that the .sav file has some German Words, that SAS cannot understand.

Is there a command that loads a library or something in SAS so that it can understand language-specific values?

P.S. I have also found a similar post here: [Importing Polish character file in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723171/importing-polish-character-file-in-sas)
but the answer is not really clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS by default is often installed using the standard windows-latin-1 codepage, often called "ASCII" (incorrectly).  SAS itself can handle any encoding, but if it by default uses Windows-Latin-1, it won't handle some Unicode translations.

If you're using SAS 9.3 or 9.4, and possibly earlier versions of v9, you probably have a Unicode version of SAS installed.  Look in

```
\SasFoundation\9.x\nls\
```

In there you'll probably find "en" (if you're using it in English, anyway), which is usually using the default Windows-latin-1 codepage.  You'll also find (possibly, if it was installed) Unicode compatible versions.  This is really just a configuration setting, but it's important enough to get them right that they supply a pre-baked config file.

In my case I have a "u8" folder under nls, which I can then use to enable Unicode character encoding on my datasets and when I read in data.

One caveat: I don't know for sure how well the SPSS import engine handles Unicdoe/MBCS characters.  This is a separate issue; if you run the unicode version of SAS and it still has problems, that may be the issue, and you may need to either export your SPSS file differently or talk to SAS tech support.

Comment: Thank for your comment Joe. I am new to SAS, so could you please be a bit more specific? I am running SAS 9.3 and have indeed located the folder you mentioned ("u8") under \SasFoundation\9.x\nls\. However, how can I use it? Is there a way to launch SAS in Unicode encoding and run my syntax again, or is there a command to add in my editor to import a file from "u8" so that it can read German characters?

Comment: Your SAS shortcut should have a -config option in it; that will point to your default config file.  Replace that with the filename and path of the /u8 file.

Comment: Thank you , Joe I found what you were talking about.