# SAS: Change encoding in proc import

Tags: sas

I've got proc import from xlsx file with column names in polish language.

My simple proc looks like this:

```
proc import datafile = '/directory/file_name.XLSX'

 out  = libname.tablename
 dbms  =  xlsx
 replace;

run;
```

I would like to add somewhere `ENCODING="LATIN2"` so the columns don't look like:

[image]

Is it possible? And how?

I could do it in second step by renaming all the columns with some predefined list. but I don't want to do it like this yet. Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: What are the actual characters in the first row of the XLSX sheet?  What are the hex codes of the characters in the names that proc import created?  Are they the same bytes or has SAS transcoded them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding of the file you are reading/importing.

Per [SAS support](https://support.sas.com/kb/41/925.html), this can be specified in the filename statement.

I've tested it with SAS UE and csv files and it worked pretty well:

```
filename temp '/folders/myfolders/Raw data/iso8859.csv' encoding="utf-8";

proc import datafile = temp

 out  = utf8
 dbms  =  csv
 replace;

run;
```

Your code should then look like:

```
filename temp '/directory/file_name.XLSX' encoding="LATIN2";

proc import datafile = temp

 out  = libname.tablename
 dbms  =  xlsx
 replace;

run;
```

Comment: I did exactly as you stated above and it didn't work. I wonder if this is not a problem with license as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723171/importing-polish-character-file-in-sas

Comment: Hmm it seems you can, because obviously you can import something. If your SAS install doesn't have Access to PC file then you would not get anything. You can check with `proc setinit; run;`. What does SAS log say? And does import work with weird characters, or does it simply fail?

Comment: Which exactly part of log would you like to see? `Version: 9.04.01M5P091317` also `Operating system:    LIN X64 .`. The code works and it imports both columns and data inside with some funny characters.

Comment: Maybe `LATIN2` is windows and not linux enoding?

Comment: For proc setinit, if you see "Access to PC file" at the end of the output, then you have what is needed for reading from an XLSX file. But for you it imports fine so you have it, I'm sure of this. I tried with a XLSX file myself and it worked fine, whatever encoding I specified. Have you tried without specifying any encoding? It would let SAS assume what encoding is, and I believe there is only one possible encoding for an XLSX file. As a backup solution, maybe you could try to export your XLSX file to CSV or TXT and see what happens?

Comment: I got some knowledge of what probably is happening. The files are moved from windows location to linux location (by mapped drive). SAS sits on linux. The linux probably has different encoding and it makes funny characters. SAS just imports them already wrong. I will try to open that .csv file with notepad directly on linux server and see how it looks like. I will post what i found out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on here:

1. You can't control the encoding of the XLSX format file; that's a binary file (sort of), and SAS doesn't treat it like a text file.  You *can* do this for CSVs, as that's read in as a text file, but not XLSX.
2. If you're importing a file in another encoding into SAS, your session encoding also matters.  You will have to run your SAS session in the right encoding to have everything look right.  See [the documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/nlsref/p1tktrbvawjqtzn180bw7al9wl5k.htm) for more details on how to change your SAS session encoding.

But, there's a third option here, if you just want to get rid of the extra characters: `options validvarname=v7` (or even `v6`).  I believe this will prevent SAS's import engine from using any character other than A-Z 0-9 and underscore. It won't necessarily look pretty, though, it'll replace all of the other characters with underscores I suspect.